# SQL Server TRIM character

Tags: sql, character, trim

I have the following string: 'BOB*', how do I trim the * so it shows up as 'BOB'

I tried the RTRIM('BOB*','*') but does not work as says needs only 1 parameter.

Comment: New answer to an old question...If you are using SQL Server 2017, the [TRIM() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184512/left-trim-newlines-in-tsql/49477253#49477253) may be a solution for some of you.

Comment: Given how specific the accepted answer is, i suggest `SELECT 'BOB'` as a more performant alternative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
LEFT('BOB*', LEN('BOB*')-1)
```

should do it.

Comment: This will remove the last character from the string, whether or not that character is an asterisk. This works in the special case of strings that end with an asterisk, but doesn't do any check whether the last character should be removed or not.

Comment: It doesn't trim more than one asterisk either.

Comment: The original question didn't say "I only want to remove an asterisk if there's one there" or "I want to remove all asterisks no matter how many there are". I answered the question that was asked.

Comment: it will remove last character from the value regardless the character is special or alpha or numeric, it is not a generic solution at all. If you do only for `'BOB'` so the result will be `'BO'` which is not a valid according to question.

Comment: It isn't a generic solution, because it isn't a generic question. It's a very specific question about one string.

Comment: **`LEFT('BOB*',3)`**

Comment: That's an even less generic solution than mine - well done!

Answer (score 27):

Another pretty good way to implement Oracle's `TRIM char FROM string` in **MS SQL Server** is the following:

- First, you need to identify a char that will never be used in your string, for example `~`
- You replace all spaces with that character
- You replace the character `*` you want to trim with a space
- You `LTrim` + `RTrim` the obtained string
- You replace back all spaces with the trimmed character `*`
- You replace back all never-used characters with a space

For example:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(LTrim(RTrim(REPLACE(REPLACE(string,' ','~'),'*',' '))),' ','*'),'~',' ')
```

Comment: This is great.  I adapted a version of this to remove the preceeding '[' and ']' from strings, which was useful to detect if they were db object nouns (tables, sp's, etc)

Comment: From SQL Server vNext you could use TRIM function like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41366032/5070879

Answer (score 22):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TrimCharacter
(
    @Value NVARCHAR(4000),
    @CharacterToTrim NVARCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Value))
    SET @Value = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Value, PATINDEX('%[^'+@CharacterToTrim+']%', @Value), LEN(@Value)))
    SET @Value = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Value, PATINDEX('%[^'+@CharacterToTrim+']%', @Value), LEN(@Value)))
    RETURN @Value
END
GO
--- Example
----- SELECT dbo.TrimCharacter('***BOB*********', '*')
----- returns 'BOB'
```

Comment: this answer needs some love

Answer (score 13):

If you want to remove all asterisks then it's obvious:

```
SELECT REPLACE('Hello*', '*', '')
```

**However**, If you have more than one asterisk at the end and multiple throughout, but are only interested in trimming the trailing ones, then I'd use this:

```
DECLARE @String VarChar(50) = '**H*i****'
SELECT LEFT(@String, LEN(REPLACE(@String, '*', ' ')))              --Returns: **H*i
```

I updated this answer to include show how to remove leading characters:

```
SELECT RIGHT(@String, LEN(REPLACE(REVERSE(@String), '*', ' ')))    --Returns: H*i****
```

LEN() has a "*feature*" (that looks a lot like a bug) where it does not count trailing spaces.

Comment: This way you'd be trimming any space at the end. Also you are relying on a bug that is likely to be corrected now or then...

Comment: @Teejay There's no way that the behaviour of `LEN` will be changed now for backwards compatibility reasons. The ignoring trailing white space is how it is documented to work so won't be acknowledged as a bug.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted behavior similar to how RTRIM handles spaces  i.e. that "B*O*B**" would turn into "B*O*B" without losing the embedded ones then something like -

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE('B*O*B**'), PATINDEX('%[^*]%',REVERSE('B*O*B**')), LEN('B*O*B**') - PATINDEX('%[^*]%', REVERSE('B*O*B**')) + 1))
```

Should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately this method cannot trim `]` and `^` (see my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290737). I wrote two small functiona that implement `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` on MsSql server, see my self-answer in the same page linked above.

Comment: this works, but only right trims the value... what would be the optimal way to trim both sides?

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to remove a single `'*'` character from the value when the value ends with a `'*'`, a simple CASE expression will do that for you:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(foo,1) = '*' THEN LEFT(foo,LEN(foo)-1) ELSE foo END AS foo
  FROM (SELECT 'BOB*' AS foo)
```

To remove all trailing `'*'` characters, then you'd need a more complex expression, making use of the `REVERSE`, `PATINDEX`, `LEN` and `LEFT` functions.

**NOTE:** Be careful with the REPLACE function, as that will replace *all* occurrences of the specified character within the string, not just the trailing ones.

Answer (score 2):

How about.. (in this case to trim off trailing comma or period)

For a variable:

```
-- Trim commas and full stops from end of City
WHILE RIGHT(@CITY, 1) IN (',', '.'))    
    SET @CITY = LEFT(@CITY, LEN(@CITY)-1)
```

For table values:

```
-- Trim commas and full stops from end of City
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [sap_out_address] WHERE RIGHT([CITY], 1) IN (',', '.'))     
    UPDATE [sap_out_address]    
    SET [CITY] = LEFT([CITY], LEN([CITY])-1)  
    WHERE RIGHT([CITY], 1) IN (',', '.')
```

Answer (score 2):

An other approach ONLY if you want to remove leading and trailing characters is the use of TRIM function.
By default removes white spaces but have te avility of remove other characters if you specify its.

`SELECT TRIM('=' FROM '=SPECIALS=') AS Result;`

```
Result  
--------
SPECIALS
```

Unfortunately `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` does not work in the same way and only removes white spaces instead of specified characters like TRIM does if you specify its.

> Reference and more examples:
>   https://database.guide/how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-characters-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

RRIM() LTRIM() only remove spaces   try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Basically just replace the * with empty space

REPLACE('TextWithCharacterToReplace','CharacterToReplace','CharacterToReplaceWith')

So you want

REPLACE ('BOB*','*','')

Comment: This will replace  all the * in the string, not only the leading and trailing ones.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Teejay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14647204/1028230), and almost stopped there. It's clever, but I got the "almost too clever" feeling, as, somehow, your string at some point will actually have a `~` (or whatever) in it on purpose. So that's not defensive enough for me to put into production.

I like [Chris' too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20431096/1028230), but the `PATINDEX` call seems like overkill.

Though it's probably a [micro-optimization](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/), here's one without `PATINDEX`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIMMIT(@stringToTrim NVARCHAR(MAX), @charToTrim NCHAR(1))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @retVal NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @retVal = @stringToTrim

    WHILE 1 = charindex(@charToTrim, reverse(@retVal))
        SET @retVal = SUBSTRING(@retVal,0,LEN(@retVal))

    WHILE 1 = charindex(@charToTrim, @retVal)
        SET @retVal = SUBSTRING(@retVal,2,LEN(@retVal))

    RETURN @retVal
END

--select dbo.TRIMMIT('\\trim\asdfds\\\', '\')
--trim\asdfds
```

Returning a `MAX` nvarchar bugs me a little, but that's the most flexible way to do this..

Comment: I like this answer, however it may return expected results for some cases. For example `select dbo.TRIMMIT('\trim\asdfds       ', '\')` (There are multiple space characters after `asdfds` but SO trims them!) returns `trim\asdfds `, because [function LEN returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You may need to use `datalength` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a similar approach to some of the above answers of using pattern matching and reversing the string to find the first non-trimmable character, then cutting that off.  The difference is this version does less work than those above, so should be a little more efficient.

- This creates `RTRIM` functionality for any specified character.
- It includes an additional step `set @charToFind = case...` to escape the chosen character.
- There is currently an issue if `@charToReplace` is a right crotchet (`]`) as there appears to be no way to escape this.

.

```
declare @stringToSearch nvarchar(max) = '****this is****a  ** demo*****'
, @charToFind nvarchar(5) = '*' 

--escape @charToFind so it doesn't break our pattern matching
set @charToFind = case @charToFind 
    when ']' then '[]]' --*this does not work / can't find any info on escaping right crotchet*
    when '^' then '\^'
    --when '%' then '%' --doesn't require escaping in this context
    --when '[' then '[' --doesn't require escaping in this context
    --when '_' then '_' --doesn't require escaping in this context
    else @charToFind
end

select @stringToSearch
, left
(
    @stringToSearch
    ,1 
    + len(@stringToSearch)
    - patindex('%[^' + @charToFind  + ']%',reverse(@stringToSearch))
)
```

Comment: Post to investigate my `]` issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779665/how-to-match-all-characters-except-right-crotchet-close-square-bracket-with-sq

Answer (score 1):

SqlServer2017 has a new way to do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

SELECT TRIM('0' FROM '00001900'); -> 19

SELECT TRIM( '.,! ' FROM  '#     test    .'); -> #     test

SELECT TRIM('*' FROM 'BOB*'); --> BOB

Unfortunately, RTRIM does not support trimming a specific character.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT REPLACE('BOB*', '*', '')  
    SELECT REPLACE('B*OB*', '*', '') 
-------------------------------------
     Result : BOB
-------------------------------------
```

this will replace all asterisk* from the text

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Original**

```
select replace('BOB*','*','')
```

**Fixed to be an exact replacement**

```
select replace('BOB*','BOB*','BOB')
```

Comment: This will replace  all the * in the string, not only the leading and trailing ones.

Comment: Good point.  I have corrected the sample.  However I must point out that the string being passed is a literal, so there is only one star in it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Trim with many cases

```
--id = 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111
select right(id,2)+1  from ordertbl -- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11  -- last     two positions are taken

select LEFT('BOB', LEN('BOB')-1) -- BO

select LEFT('BOB*',1) --B
select LEFT('BOB*',2) --BO
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for one char parameter:

rtrim('0000100','0') ->
select left('0000100',len(rtrim(replace('0000100','0',' '))))

ltrim('0000100','0') ->
select right('0000100',len(replace(ltrim(replace('0000100','0',' ')),' ','.')))

Answer (score 0):

@teejay solution is great. But the code below can be more understandable:

```
declare @X nvarchar(max)='BOB *'

set @X=replace(@X,' ','^')

set @X=replace(@X,'*',' ')

set @X= ltrim(rtrim(@X))

set @X=replace(@X,'^',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I used in the past. Note that while you can make it more general purpose by having extra parameters like the character(s) you wish to remove and what you will be replacing the space character(s) with, this greatly increases execution time.  Here, I used a pipe to replace spaces AFTER pre-trimming the input. Change varchar to nvarchar if required.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TrimColons] 
    (
        @strToTrim varchar(500)
    )
    RETURNS varchar(500)
    AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@strToTrim)),' ','|'),':',' '))),' ',':'),'|',' ')
    
        /*
        Here's a breakdown of this fancy, schmancy, trimmer
    
        LTRIM(RTRIM(@strToTrim))  trims leading & trailing spaces first
        REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@strToTrim)),' ','|')  replaces inside spaces with pipe char
        REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@strToTrim)),' ','|'),':',' ') replaces demarc character, the colon, with spaces
        LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@strToTrim)),' ','|'),':',' ')))  trims the leading & trailing  converted-to-space demarc char (colon) 
        REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@strToTrim)),' ','|'),':',' '))),' ',':') replaces the inner space characters back to demar char (colon)
        REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@strToTrim)),' ','|'),':',' '))),' ',':'),'|',' ') replaces the pipe characters back to original space characters
    
        */
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @String VarChar(50) = '**H*i****', @String2 VarChar(50)

--Assign to new variable @String2
;WITH X AS (
SELECT LEFT(@String, LEN(REPLACE(@String, '*', ' '))) [V1]
)
SELECT TOP 1 @String2 = RIGHT(V1, LEN(REPLACE(REVERSE(V1), '*', ' '))) FROM X

SELECT @String [@String], @String2 [@String2]

--See the intermediate values, v0 original, v1 triming end, and v2 trim the v1 leading
;WITH X AS (
SELECT @String V0,  LEFT(@String, LEN(REPLACE(@String, '*', ' '))) [V1]
)
SELECT [V0], [V1], RIGHT([V1], LEN(REPLACE(REVERSE([V1]), '*', ' '))) [v2] FROM X
```