# Escaping ] and ^ characters in a T-SQL "pattern" expression character class

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, escaping, patindex

I'm trying to emulate Oracle's `RTRIM(expression, characters)` in MsSql Server 2008 R2 with the following query:

```
REVERSE(
        SUBSTRING(
                  REVERSE(field),
                  PATINDEX('%[^chars]%', REVERSE(field)),
                  LEN(field) - PATINDEX('%[^chars]%', REVERSE(field)) + 1
             )
       )
```

The problem is that I want to be able to trim characters like `]` and `^` which do probably need escaping.

I don't know how to do this. Things like `\]` don't work.

I'm aware of the `ESCAPE` clause but I do not understand exactly how it works and, by the way, SqlServer refuses it if put right after the pattern string.

Fun fact:

If I write `%[^^]%` (desiring to trim `^`) it doesn't work.

If I write `%[^ ^]%` it does trim `^`, but clearly also trim spaces!

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3661145/27535

Comment: The problem is that the `]` closes the character class. In RegExp you use `\ `  to escape a `]` in a char class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this document on MS Connect:
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/259534/patindex-missing-escape-clause

The user asks about `ESCAPE` clause with `PATINDEX`, then another user extends the request for `CHARINDEX` as well.

MS answer: **Ticket closed as *Won't fix*** :(

I finished writing my own custom function for `LTrim`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION LTrim_Chars (
  @BaseString varchar(2000),
  @TrimChars varchar(100)
)

RETURNS varchar(2000) AS

BEGIN

  DECLARE @TrimCharFound bit

  DECLARE @BaseStringPos int
  DECLARE @TrimCharsPos int

  DECLARE @BaseStringLen int
  DECLARE @TrimCharsLen int

  IF @BaseString IS NULL OR @TrimChars IS NULL
  BEGIN
      RETURN NULL
  END

  SET @BaseStringPos = 1

  SET @BaseStringLen = LEN(@BaseString)
  SET @TrimCharsLen = LEN(@TrimChars)

  WHILE @BaseStringPos <= @BaseStringLen
  BEGIN 

      SET @TrimCharFound = 0
      SET @TrimCharsPos = 1

      WHILE @TrimCharsPos <= @TrimCharsLen
      BEGIN     
          IF SUBSTRING(@BaseString, @BaseStringPos, 1) = SUBSTRING(@TrimChars, @TrimCharsPos, 1)
          BEGIN
              SET @TrimCharFound = 1
              BREAK
          END             
          SET @TrimCharsPos = @TrimCharsPos + 1     
      END

      IF @TrimCharFound = 0
      BEGIN
        RETURN SUBSTRING(@BaseString, @BaseStringPos, @BaseStringLen - @BaseStringPos + 1)
      END       
      SET @BaseStringPos = @BaseStringPos + 1

  END

  RETURN ''

END
```

And for `RTrim`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RTrim_Chars (
  @BaseString varchar(2000),
  @TrimChars varchar(100)
)

RETURNS varchar(2000) AS

BEGIN

  RETURN REVERSE(LTrim_Chars(REVERSE(@BaseString), @TrimChars))

END
```

At least, I learnt some MsSql scripting...

---

**EDIT:**

I added `NULL` checks for the two arguments, to reflect Oracle and Postgres' behavior.

Unfortunately, Oracle still behaves slightly differently:
in the case you write `LTRIM(string, '')`, it returns `NULL`, since a 0-length string is like `NULL` in Oracle, so it's actually returning the result of `LTRIM(string, NULL)`, which is `NULL` indeed.

BTW, this is a really strange case.

Comment: Going through the input character by character in a `WHILE` loop (and a nested one at that!) might be less efficient than my proposal.

Comment: Normally, I'll trim 1-2 characters, so a performance degradation should be an issue. Anyway, I'll check your function out better! Thanks

Comment: Also note that my solution supports character ranges as in `a-z` or `0-9`. This could come in handy.

Comment: Yes, I see. But it has some basic issue... See my comment on your answer

Comment: @Tomalak Also, I appreciate your effort to support ranges, but I actually need a clone of the Oracle function. We rely on a DB-indipendence layer that builds DDLs & DMLs for *Oracle* / *PgSql* / *MsSql*.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. In fact range support is a side-effect of me using `PATINDEX`, so it was not really intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RTRIMCHARS(
    @input AS VARCHAR(MAX), @chars AS VARCHAR(100)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @charpos BIGINT
    DECLARE @strpos BIGINT

    SET @strpos = LEN(@input)
    SET @charpos = LEN(@chars)

    IF @strpos IS NULL OR @charpos IS NULL RETURN NULL
    IF @strpos = 0 OR @charpos = 0 RETURN @input

    WHILE @strpos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @charpos = LEN(@chars)
        WHILE @charpos > 0
        BEGIN
            IF SUBSTRING(@chars, @charpos, 1) = SUBSTRING(@input, @strpos, 1)
            BEGIN
                SET @strpos = @strpos - 1
                BREAK
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @charpos = @charpos - 1
            END
        END
        IF @charpos = 0 BREAK
    END
    RETURN SUBSTRING(@input, 1, @strpos)
END
```

Usage

```
SELECT dbo.RTRIMCHARS('bla%123', '123%')   -- 'bla'
SELECT dbo.RTRIMCHARS('bla%123', '123')    -- 'bla%'
SELECT dbo.RTRIMCHARS('bla%123', 'xyz')    -- 'bla%123'
SELECT dbo.RTRIMCHARS('bla%123', ']')      -- 'bla%123'
SELECT dbo.RTRIMCHARS('bla%123', '')       -- 'bla%123'
SELECT dbo.RTRIMCHARS('bla%123', NULL)     -- NULL
SELECT dbo.RTRIMCHARS(NULL, '123')         -- NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I finished writing my own one. Check it out :)

Comment: Your function seems not to work fine: If I call `RTRIMCHARS('[PROJECT]', 'E')` it returns `[PROJ`

Comment: @Teejay Should it not cut the input at the first occurrence of `E`? What would be the output on Oracle?

Comment: On EVERY coding language that implements LTrim/RTrim, they work like following: `LTRIM("eeeesomestring", "e") = "somestring"` and `RTRIM("somestringnnn", "n") = "somestring"`

Comment: I mean it should cut all trimchars until the first non-trimchar is found. So, in `RTRIMCHARS('[PROJECT]', 'E')`, since the first char at right is a non-trimchar, the function should return the entire string `[PROJECT]`

Comment: @Teejay I've fixed my code to work according to spec. Alas, it uses a nested loop as well, now. ;-) I'll vote your's up for coming up with your own solution; I just did not want to have broken code sit in one of my answers. If you want, please make a benchmark against your function, I'd be very interested in your findings!

Comment: Yes, yours is an R-Trim one... Needing both L and R trims, I decided to wrote the simpler one (L) and then use it to also implement the other (R).

Comment: I found out that a native `LTRIM(str)` (like mine) or a native `RTRIM(str)` (like yours) runs about 20% faster than a `REVERSE(LTRIM(REVERSE(str)))`, though the latter gains in code-maintainability, since you've to edit only one function.

Comment: As a side note, I implemented the same function in PLSQL (Oracle) and it responds within times similar to the stock `LTRIM`. Basically, even the native function needs to do the same operations.