# sql server - how do i find rows with whitespace in a column

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, whitespace

I want to do something like

```
select * from X where string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a)
```

Column a is `NOT NULL`

So what would be the equivalent of C# `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` in T-SQL to get all rows where column a has only whitespace (combination of multiple spaces or tabs)?

Also, I would rather avoid using [clr](/questions/tagged/clr) functions.

Comment: How about `ISBLANK()`?

Comment: You also want to consider columns with `NULL` values as being whitespace?

Comment: no - column is not null - will make an edit.

Comment: @TrippKinetics I have sql server 2008 r2. i am getting - 'ISBLANK' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @TrippKinetics ISBLANK won't work for TSQL

Comment: "Whitespace" defines a broad set: spaces (at least 20 different kinds), non-breaking spaces, line separators, tabulations, paragraph separators, etc.  Can you narrow the scope, or do you need to design defensively because this is a sanitizing pass?

Comment: FYI: Here is Microsoft's definition of whitespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx

Comment: @Anon OP did narrow.  C# string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace

Comment: @Anon But you changed words.  IsNullOrWhiteSpace is a defined set.  "Whitespace" in my mind is general.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try this:

```
select * 
from yourtable
where ltrim(rtrim(yourcolumn)) = ''
```

The idea is that if trimming the value leaves you with an empty string, then all you had in the first place was whitespace.

You could also just do this:

```
select *
from yourtable
where yourcolumn like ' '
```

Note that I have tested the second query on SQL Server 2008 R2, and it doesn't work on 2014 as stated in the comments by @gunr2171

Finally, if you have tab, carriage return or line feed, the above will not work. What you can do is to first replace these values with a blank string, and then use the first query like so:

```
select * 
from yourtable
where ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(yourcolumn,char(9),''),char(10),''),char(13),''))) = ''
```

`char(9)`,`char(10)` and `char(13)` are used for tab, line feed and carriage return respectively.

Comment: Doesn't handle NULL values.

Comment: "Column a is NOT NULL" - OP said it's not going to be, hence not handling nulls.

Comment: Your second example would only work if the value is a single space.

Comment: That's what I thought initially as well, but it does for multiple spaces too. Demo: http://rextester.com/ACUUL22481

Comment: Not working for me with 2014 server. `declare @temp nvarchar(max) = '      '; if(@temp like ' ') print 'yes'`

Comment: @gunr2171 Fair enough, I'm testing on 2008 R2 and have no access to 2014.

Comment: selecting this as answer - the first statement works well enough for me.

Comment: The second example would work with wildcards I think, where yourcolumn like '% %'

Answer (score 12):

I just had a problem with this particular situation, i needed to find and clean every field with white spaces, but i found 4 types of possibles white space in my database fields (Reference to [ASCII code table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)):

- Horizontal Tab(char(9))
- New Line(char(10))
- Vertical Tab(char(9))
- Space(char(32))

Maybe this query can help you.

```
SELECT @COLUMN
FROM @TABLE
WHERE @COLUMN like '%'+CHAR(9)+'%' or @COLUMN like '%'+CHAR(10)+'%'
or @COLUMN like '%'+CHAR(11)+'%' or @COLUMN like '%'+CHAR(32)+'%'
```

Comment: This to me is the simplest solution

Comment: Except this would select something with values like "hello world" where the whitespace in the middle is one of those 4 characters. OP asked for rows where it has only whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

Based on shree.pat18's comment, here's a possible answer...

```
select * 
from yourtable
where ltrim(rtrim(yourcolumn)) = '' or yourcolumn is null
```

I think that should do the trick

Comment: Not sure if this is correct but it would be my first try.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Method `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` checks for [25 different unicode whitespace characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=netframework-4.8.1#remarks). For an equivalent check in SQL Server 2017+ we can use the [TRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
DECLARE @whitespaces nvarchar(50) =
    NCHAR(0x0020) + NCHAR(0x00A0) + NCHAR(0x1680) + NCHAR(0x1680) + NCHAR(0x2001)
    + NCHAR(0x2002) + NCHAR(0x2003) + NCHAR(0x2004) + NCHAR(0x2005) + NCHAR(0x2006)
    + NCHAR(0x2007) + NCHAR(0x2008) + NCHAR(0x2009) + NCHAR(0x200A) + NCHAR(0x202F)
    + NCHAR(0x205F) + NCHAR(0x3000) + NCHAR(0x2028) + NCHAR(0x2029) + NCHAR(0x0009)
    + NCHAR(0x000A) + NCHAR(0x000B) + NCHAR(0x000C) + NCHAR(0x000D) + NCHAR(0x0085);

SELECT *
FROM X
WHERE a IS NULL OR TRIM(@whitespaces FROM a) = ''
```

Since in this question `a` is not null, that part can be left out from the `WHERE` clause.

---

In lower versions of SQL Server, trimming specific characters requires a bit more effort, so in most cases, a regular [LTRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) should be enough. But if you do need the exact C# equivalent, you can see how to trim specific characters here:

- [SQL Server TRIM character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838676/sql-server-trim-character)
- [How to trim string using predefined special characters in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35486423/12162243)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
select *
from x
where len(ltrim(rtrim(coalesce(a,'')))) = 0
```

After examining my query it would appear redundant to use ltrim AND rtrim, just use one or the other.

the following will suffice

```
select *
from x
where len(ltrim(coalesce(a,''))) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For full ASCII whitespace (tabs, line feeds, spaces, etc) and the flexibility to add other characters as needed, i.e CHAR(0):

```
WITH
  num256 AS (
     SELECT TOP 256 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) n
     FROM master.dbo.spt_values
  ),
  filter AS (
    SELECT CHAR(n-1) c FROM num256
    WHERE n NOT IN (0x09,0x0A,0x0B,0x0C,0x0D,0x20,0x85,0xA0)
  )
SELECT MyColumn
FROM MyTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM filter
  WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%'+c+'%'
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of an If statement that checks if a variable is null or whitespace (c# equivalent of `IsNullOrWhitespace`).

```
declare @temp nvarchar(max) = '      ';

if(@temp is null
    or
   LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@temp))) = 0)
begin
    print 'it is empty or null'
end
```

You can make this inline by including the logic in a where clause.

```
select *
from someTable
where
    aValue is null
        or
    LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(aValue))) = 0
```

Comment: Having both LTRIM and RTRIM is redundant. If there is any character in the value no matter how many trims you throw at it it will still have that character.