# How to trim string using predefined special characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, trim

I want to trim SQL Server strings using some special characters such as "،,.?!؛,،,><=+ـ".

The SQL server ltrim and rtrim functions only strips the space characters.

```
DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(100) = N',,,,,!؛Computation+Time, Cost،,.?!؛,،,><=+ـ'
SELECT dbo.SpecialTrim(@Str, N'،,.?!؛,،,><=+ـ')

The result : Computation+Time, Cost
```

Have anyone any ideas in order to implement SpecialTrim function?

Comment: Are you looking for [**`REPLACE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186862.aspx), maybe?

Comment: Using nested replace for this is the simplest and fastest way to deal with this.

Comment: Do you mean just one of these characters, or any of them at the same time?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838676/sql-server-trim-character

Comment: You can try creating a function which will parse each string in a loop and remove each of these characters. Mind you, this is a little more complicated.

Comment: @ARZ Looks cool, but it would depend on the data. OP, can you post some sample data?

Comment: This might be also of help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu replace would remove all instances not just those at the beginning and end.

Comment: You could knock up a CLR function that uses the [String.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: CLR seems a bit heavy for something so simple.

Comment: @SeanLange - Disagree - it will be trivial to write and out perform any TSQL method.

Comment: @MartinSmith but CLR for some super basic replace is overkill. Sure it is simple to write it but it is like hunting flies with a bazooka.

Comment: @SeanLange -  So lets see the TSQL code that trims the desired characters from the beginning and end of `،,.?!؛,،,><=.the quick brown fox،,.?!؛,،,><=.jumped over the lazy dog،,.?!؛,،,><=.` and leaves the ones in the middle of the string alone.

Comment: We still don't really know if the OP wants to remove all instances or just the beginning/trailing. For the example you posted then I would agree that CLR would be the simplest.

Comment: Actually I have thought of a TSQL way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below hardcodes the pattern.

It looks for the first character that is *not* one of the characters to exclude at both ends.

To make it dynamic you could build up the set of characters using string concatenation (be careful of characters containing special meaning in the pattern syntax)

```
WITH T(String) AS
(
SELECT 'Computation+Time, Cost،,.?!؛,،,><=+ـ' union all
SELECT ',,,,,!؛Computation+Time, Cost،,.?!؛,،,><=+ـ' union all
SELECT 'Computation+Time, Cost،,.?!؛,،,><=+ـ' union all
SELECT 'Computation+Time, Cost' union all
SELECT ''
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(String,Start,len(String) + 2 - Start - Finish)
FROM T
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT  PATINDEX('%[^،,.?!؛,،,><=+ـ]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin,String),
        PATINDEX('%[^،,.?!؛,،,><=+ـ]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin,REVERSE(String))
)ca(Start, Finish)
```

Answer (score 2):

From **SQL Server vNext** and on you could use built-in [`TRIM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt775029.aspx) function:

> **TRIM**
>
> Removes white spaces or specified characters from a string.
>
> ```
> TRIM ( [ characters FROM ] string )
> ```
>
> Returns a character expression with a type of string argument where white spaces or specified characters are removed from both sides. Returns NULL if input string is NULL.

In your case:

```
DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(100) = N',,,,,!؛Computation+Time, Cost،,.?!؛,،,><=+ـ';
SELECT TRIM(N'،,.?!؛,،,><=+ـ' FROM @Str);
```

Comment: Simply looks, simply works.