# Left Trim Newlines in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, newline, trim

I try to left trim the newlines in tsql. So I want to remove the leading 
        CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
of my data in a Field. And ensure that the other newlines will not be removed.

**I mean this:**

```
'
Kanne Oliver
Rosa-Luxemburg-Str. 3
07817 Alton ( Elster)'
```

**Should be this:**

```
'Kanne Oliver
Rosa-Luxemburg-Str. 3
07817 Alton ( Elster)'
```

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 8):

In this very specific example, SQL Server 2017's [TRIM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) function could be used. It removes characters from both the beginning and end of a string to text. By default `TRIM` removes space `CHAR(32)` characters only. Here, the characters to be removed (CR and LF) will be specified:

```
SELECT TRIM( CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) FROM '
Kanne Oliver
Rosa-Luxemburg-Str. 3
07817 Alton ( Elster)');
```

NOTE: in SQL Server Management Studio, it will be helpful to set "Query Results to Text" (CTRL + T) to effectively see the results:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Kanne Oliver
Rosa-Luxemburg-Str. 3
07817 Alton ( Elster)

(1 row affected)
```

Also note that if there were any CR or LF characters at the end of the string of text, those would be removed too. Unfortunately, `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` still only work for space characters (as of SQL 2017).

Answer (score 5):

If every row of the data have the CR LF at the begin just strip them from the rows

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(3, LEN(field)) field
FROM   Table
```

otherwise, if not all rows begin with CR LF you need to check from it

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) = LEFT(field, 2)
            THEN SUBSTRING(field, 3, LEN(field))
            ELSE field
       END
FROM   Table
```

---

The queries before this will only remove the first CR LF, to remove any number of them it' possible to use recursive `CTE`

```
WITH S AS (
  SELECT sentence 
       = CASE WHEN char(13) + char(10) = LEFT(sentence, 2) 
              THEN SUBSTRING(sentence, 3, LEN(sentence))
              ELSE sentence
         END
  FROM   Test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sentence = SUBSTRING(sentence, 3, LEN(sentence))
  FROM   S
  WHERE  char(13) + char(10) = LEFT(sentence, 2)
)
select Sentence
FROM   S
WHERE  char(13) + char(10) <> LEFT(sentence, 2)
```

or, as Filip De Vos pointed out in a comment, search for the first char that is not CR LF

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(sentence
               , PATINDEX('%[^' + char(13) + char(10) + ']%', sentence)
               , LEN(sentence))
FROM   test
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb571/2) with both queries

Comment: It doesn't work as ltrim() since your approach will only remove the first crlf. It does fix the example though

Comment: you can do `substring(field, patindex('%[^' + char(13) + char(10) + ']%', @str), len(field))`

Comment: You can keep it in ;)

Comment: if you change the pattern to `'%[^' + char(13) + char(10) + ',^ ]%'` it will skip whitespace also ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP want that, in my demo data I added space between newline to be sure that the query will stop at them

Answer (score 0):

```
    SET ANSCHRIFT =
    CASE 
    WHEN LEFT(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(ANSCHRIFT, 5, LEN(ANSCHRIFT)-4)),2) = CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)
    THEN SUBSTRING(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(ANSCHRIFT, 5,LEN(ANSCHRIFT)-4)),3,LEN(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(ANSCHRIFT, 5, LEN(ANSCHRIFT)-4)))-2)
    ELSE LTRIM(SUBSTRING(ANSCHRIFT, 5, LEN(ANSCHRIFT)-4))
    END
```

Has managed this!

ANSCHRIFT stands for the column name which contained the data. Thanks for the ideas and help.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove new lines from the data.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(YourColumn, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') AS CleanedColumn
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score -3):

The RTRIM function in Transact-SQL returns a character string after truncating all trailing blanks while LTRIM returns a character expression after it removes leading blanks.

So to remove leading or trailing blanks from a string, you could just write as below:

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(YourColumnName)) AS FirstName FROM [dbo].[StaffInformation]
```

Comment: `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` don't remove CR LF, if you try to run `SELECT LEN(LTRIM(char(13) + char(10) + 'Foo'))` it'll return 5 not 3