# How to Specify Trim Chars in SQL TRIM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a table Employee, in that some values are started with ", ". So, I need to remove the **comma** and **white-space** at the beginning of the name at the time of **SELECT query** using **LTRIM()** - SQL-Server.

My Table : Employee

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
PersonID int,
ContactName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
); 

INSERT INTO Employee(PersonID, ContactName, Address, City)
VALUES ('1001',', B. Bala','21, Car Street','Bangalore'); 

SELECT PersonID, ContactName, Address, City FROM Employee
```

Here the ContactName Column has a value "**, B. Bala**". I need to remove the **comma** and **white-space** at the beginning of the name.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2017, the new [TRIM() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184512/left-trim-newlines-in-tsql/49477253#49477253) may work. Just be aware that `TRIM` affects both the beginning and end of the text strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use [PATINDEX()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) in order to get this done.

```
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(50) = ', Well Crap';

SELECT STUFF(@Text, 1, PATINDEX('%[A-z]%', @Text) - 1, '');
```

This would output `Well Crap`. [PATINDEX()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) will find first letter in your word and cut everything before it.

It works fine even if there's no leading rubbish:

```
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(50) = 'Mister Roboto';

SELECT STUFF(@Text, 1, PATINDEX('%[A-z]%', @Text) - 1, '');
```

This outputs `Mister Roboto`

If there are no valid characters, let's say ContactName is `, 9132124, :::`, this would output `NULL`, if you'd like to get blank result, you can use `COALESCE()`:

```
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(50) = ', 9132124, :::';

SELECT COALESCE(STUFF(@Text, 1, PATINDEX('%[A-z]%', @Text) - 1, ''), '');
```

This will output an empty string.

Comment: A small issue, a blank name would become null. Which could be a problem

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I'm aware of that. But that's really questionable. I could always add `COALESCE()` if `NULL` values are unwanted. I'll add this to answer.

Answer (score 4):

Alas, SQL Server does not support the ANSI standard functionality of specifying the characters for [`LTRIM()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx).

In this case, you can use:

```
(case when ContactName like ', %' then stuff(ContactName, 1, 2, '')
      else ContactName
 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use REPLACE.....

eg.

```
REPLACE( ' ,Your String with space comma', ' ,', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE dbo.Employee
SET        
dbo.Employee.ContactName = replace(LEFT(ContactName, 2),', ','')
+ SUBSTRING (ContactName, 3, len(contactname))
    where LEFT(ContactName, 2)=', '
```

This will only update where first two character contains **', '**